# Application dpi change on runtime - Xserver

Tags: xorg, xrandr, i3, high-dpi

I try to handle problems with Linux X-Server with mixed dpi displays.

At the office I would like to use two non HDPI displays, else I like to use the HDPI screen of my XPS13. 
The best results on the HDPI display I get with changing the dpi settings Xft.dpi

```
xrdb -merge ~/.Xdefaults
```

The last remaining problem is that the running applications do not update.

Is there a way to force an update?

Answer (score 1):

Usually X applications read the resources on startup. So unless an application is especially written for it, you can't force it to re-read the resources while running.